# How can escape HTML tag in my parameter list using CGI::escapeHTML in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with my Rails-2 application.  I have a form which submits 12 parameters.  I want to apply CGI::escapeHTML for all my params.  I knew that i can't use  like the below

CGI::escapeHTML(params). Because here **params** comes as Hash.  Is that any way available in Rails to apply this in a **effective way**. Kindly help on this. Thanks in advance.

I followed the below URL guide but i couldn't succeed.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html

Comment: Give some examples, which help us to recall the required methods.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to escape params that you want to submit? This is client side and not ruby (or rails) staff. It's task for javascript I think.

Comment: I have the form which contains list boxes, and text boxes.  Totally 12 input fields.  It i submit the form, I read  all the params by using  :params[:inputs]. For security reason I want to apply the above method. I don't want to apply 12 separate Escape Methods for all the input fields. I want to know is there any way to apply Escape method by using "Params"

Comment: Or escape on the server side after you got these params?

Comment: Yes Yevgeniy. In controller we use this. See the guide URL i have mentioned. We can handle this in Rails Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the params hash escaping the HTML.

```
params.each do |key, value| 
 params[key] = CGI::escapeHTML(value)
end
```

You probably want to select only the attributes you actually want to do this for though as the params hash also contains things like the controller and action.  e.g.

```
params[:model_name].each do |key, value| 
  params[:model_name][key] = CGI::escapeHTML(value)
end
```

From your recent comment though you'd be better off doing this in the model overriding the setters

```
def attribute_name=(value)
   self.attribute_name = CGI::escapeHTML(value)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Baloo.. This is what I am expecting.. Thank you so much